# Do people teach natural deduction when teaching set theory?

Tags: soft-question, set-theory

When I first trying to teach my self set theory (ZFC), I had trouble at proving $a \in \{a, b\}$. Starting from Axiom of Pairing

$$∀A,B\ ∃C\ ∀D.\ D ∈ C ⇔ (A=D∨B=D)$$

Then substitute $A$ with $a$, B with $b$, $C$ with $\{a, b\}$, $D$ with $a$. Get

$$a ∈ \{a,b\} ⇔ (a=a∨b=a)$$

This substitution is what I was having trouble with. I didn't know how can I remove the quantifier and replace the variables. This is why inference rules are needed. Every course I have watched from internet don't talk about natural deduction. So I am curious if people learn this when learning set theory.

Comment: Many do not and get by using general explanations of what the symbols mean, by then they would have often had a solid grounding in mathematical arguments. Note in your example that the statement you have made is true, so as $a=a$ you proved the result. Natural deduction can help gain intuition, since it formally captures deduction rules you’ll actually use

Comment: I have heard syntax and semantic should be handled separately. I guess that made me too focused on the pure symbolic part of the theory, and trying to hard to find the non semantic way to do it.

Comment: Usually, also in textbook regarding Axiomatic Set Theory, there is an initial chapter regarding logic and then the theory is developed "semi-formally", using usual mathematical proof techniques: conditional proof, proof by cases, modus ponens, universal generalization, etc

Comment: It would be nice if we can do so, but learning natural deduction also takes time and a semester is not long enough to cover the both...